# Vertical alignment of floated text

Tags: html, css-float, vertical-alignment

I need some float text to be vertically centered in a table cell full of text. This code works only with a single line, otherwise it loose its alignment.

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Content.</br>Content.</br>Content.</br>Content.</br>Content.</br>
            <span style="line-height: inherit; float: right; vertical-align: middle;">Float</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I probably can't use any other way to solve it other then the float element (no other columns for example), but I'll approciate any kind of suggestion.

Test code: http://jsfiddle.net/x49rv6dz/

Comment: Use position absolute? http://jsfiddle.net/x49rv6dz/8/

Comment: Why "probably can't"? Are you, or are you not allowed to change the html and set another cell?

Comment: The table is dynamic, absolute position can't do the trick. I can't set a new column, but I can edit the code as I like

Comment: One solution could be a nested table, but I don't like it... I can't test it until tomorrow, so I'm not even sure it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested table does exactly what I need, but I don't like it in my code (too many tables). I'm still open to any suggestion...

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px; width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Content.</br>Content.</br>Content.</br>Content.</br>Content.</br>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="line-height: inherit; float: right; vertical-align: middle;">Float</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Test code: http://jsfiddle.net/oucL931d/